# Faster way of setting instantiating objects and assigning them to an array

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, graphics, multiprocessing

I am currently developing a version of game of life using the graphics.py module. I am new to programming so do bear with me!

Currently the nested for-loop I am using can generate smaller grids fairly fast, but it gets noticeably slower around 50x50 and upwards:

```
    for i in range(self.scale, Interface.worldsize_max+2, self.scale):
            for u in range(self.scale, Interface.worldsize_max+2,self.scale):
                self.point1 = graphics.Point(i,u)
                self.point2 = graphics.Point(i-self.scale, u-self.scale)
                self.square = graphics.Rectangle(self.point1, self.point2)
                self.square.draw(self.window)
                self.square.setFill('black')
                self.grid[round(i/(Interface.worldsize_max/self.worldsize))-1][round(u/(Interface.worldsize_max/self.worldsize))-1]=self.square
```

worldsize_max is the maximum pixels of width/height of the window the program is running in. scale is worldsize_max divided by amount of columns/rows. So far I can't think of a way to make this any faster other than a) pre-generating these arrays in seperate modules and importing them(I will only have preset size options anyway Small, Medium etc) or b) using multiprocessing somehow to brute-force it. It isn't absolutely necessary to have arrays this large but it's more out of curiosity if its a limitation of my code or if it's perhaps a limitation of the graphics.py module?

Edit:
I have also noticed that as it iterates through the loop, it slows down the further it gets! How come this happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `python2.x` Use `xrange` instead of `range`.

`xrange` is more memory efficient and faster than `range`

**Reason**:
When you do `range(1,100000)` it will return an array of `100000` elements which is created in memory, where as `xrange(1,100000)` will generate the number at runtime using the current value and the step value provided to the function.

Comment: In Python 2.x yes. But in Python 3.x `xrange()` has been renamed as `range() `.

Comment: @n.abing Agreed!

Comment: I am currently using Python 3.5! Will this have any effect then?

Comment: It shouldn't have any effect if your are using 3.5, You need make the process efficient in time and space to make it faster, I will try and help to do the same and update the answer